# Prepare DEM in QGIS to open in Blender

Tags: qgis, dem, srtm, blendergis

I have been having trouble loading 30m SRTM files into blender.
I download the SRTM (DEM) 30m files from the earthdata (NASA) website and I would like to prepare them in QGIS (making mosaic, clip, reprojection) for reading in the blender, but I have not been able to. How can I do this? If possible, with step-by-step illustrations, or even a video teaching how to configure an SRTM to open in blender.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent [blog by somethingaboutmaps that goes in-depth on how to create the shaded relief in Blender.](https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/2017/11/16/creating-shaded-relief-in-blender/)

It is quite lengthy and receives updates and edits via the blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [BlenderGIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) plugin to import georeferenced images in Blender. Also, BlenderGIS can download SRTM directly into blender from inside Blender if you want. It is a very useful plugin dedicated to integrate GIS data with 3D visualization.

Here is a [blog: Shaded relief with BlenderGIS (2020)](https://wanderingcartographer.wordpress.com/2019/11/08/making-shaded-relief-with-blendergis-2019/) that explains on how to use BlenderGIS step by step to render shaded relief in Blender.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can do everything in blender, including uploading the srtm images I want for small areas (the ones we download from the earthdata website). However, in making the mosaic necessary to cover the area of ​​France, I am not having success.

Comment: @JiuDomínio you cannot upload large DEMs to Blender. Blender cannot handle such size because rendering huge files in blender will consume the whole CPU of your computer and then will crash. You need to work on small areas, yet, it will take hours to complete the rendering, if you need high quality outputs.

Comment: Blender should be able to handle almost arbitrarily large dems, so long as there's enough memory to dice the geometry you're displacing...